# yarn dev loads environment variable files multiple times

Tags: next.js

In my react/nextjs project when I run yarn dev it appears to be loading my environment variable files three times. Why? My 'scripts' in package.json just says 'next dev'.

Here is the output from the terminal:

```
yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next dev
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env.local
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env
 - ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
 - event compiled client and server successfully in 146 ms (18 modules)
 - wait compiling...
 - event compiled client and server successfully in 82 ms (18 modules)
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env.local
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env.local
 - info Loaded env from /Users/zachmoore/Documents/Development/puppypagesapp/.env
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix '**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'"
  },
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```